# Expand pandas dataframe based on range in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
Name   SICs
Agric  0100-0199
Agric  0910-0919
Agric  2048-2048
Food   2000-2009
Food   2010-2019
Soda   2097-2097
```

The `SICs` column gives  a range of integer values that match the `Name` given in the first column (although they're stored as a string).

I need to expand this DataFrame so that it has one row for each integer in the range:

```
Agric  100
Agric  101
Agric  102
...
Agric  199
Agric  910
Agric  911
...
Agric  919
Agric 2048
Food  2000
...
```

Is there a particularly good way to do this? I was going to do something like this

```
ranges = {i:r.split('-') for i, r in enumerate(inds['SICs'])}
ranges_expanded = {}
for r in ranges:
    ranges_expanded[r] = range(int(ranges[r][0]),int(ranges[r][1])+1)
```

but I wonder if there's a better way or perhaps a pandas feature to do this. (Also, I'm not sure this will work, as I don't yet see how to read the `ranges_expanded` dictionary into a DataFrame.)

Comment: Standard comment: if you insert an image, no one can copy and paste it -- they'd have to type it in.  On the other hand, if you insert *text*, we can use `pd.read_clipboard()` to easily reproduce your frame.

Comment: It seems to me that at the point you do `ranges = {i:r.split('-') for i, r in enumerate(inds['SICs'])}` you are losing the "name" information. If you manage to put all those `name`, `SIC` pairs into tuples then you can simply say `pd.DataFrame(tuples)` and will create the DataFrame for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty but I think this gets you to what you need:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

players=StringIO(u"""Name,SICs
Agric,0100-0199
Agric,0210-0211
Food,2048-2048
Soda,1198-1200""")

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(players, sep=",", parse_dates=False).reset_index()


df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Name', 'SIC'))

count = 0
for idx,r in df.iterrows():
    data = r['SICs'].split("-")
    for i in range(int(data[0]), int(data[1])+1):
                   df2.loc[count] = (r['Name'], i)
                   count += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The neatest way I found (building on from Andy Hayden's answer):

```
# Extract date min and max
df = df.set_index("Name")
df = df['SICs'].str.extract("(\d+)-(\d+)")
df.columns = ['min', 'max']
df = df.astype('int')

# Enumerate dates into wide table
enumerated_dates = [np.arange(row['min'], row['max']+1) for _, row in df.iterrows()]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=enumerated_dates, index=df.index)

# Convert from wide to long table
df = df.stack().reset_index(1, drop=True)
```

It is however slow due to the for loop. A vectorised solution would be amazing but I cant find one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use str.extract to get strings from a regular expression:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   Name       SICs
0  Agri  0100-0199
1  Agri  0910-0919
2  Food  2000-2009
```

First take out the name as that's the thing we want to keep:

```
In [12]: df1 = df.set_index("Name")

In [13]: df1
Out[13]:
           SICs
Name
Agri  0100-0199
Agri  0910-0919
Food  2000-2009

In [14]: df1['SICs'].str.extract("(\d+)-(\d+)")
Out[14]:
         0     1
Name
Agri  0100  0199
Agri  0910  0919
Food  2000  2009
```

Then flatten this with stack (which adds a MultiIndex):

```
In [15]: df1['SICs'].str.extract("(\d+)-(\d+)").stack()
Out[15]:
Name
Agri  0    0100
      1    0199
      0    0910
      1    0919
Food  0    2000
      1    2009
dtype: object
```

If you must you can remove the 0-1 level of the MultiIndex:

```
In [16]: df1['SICs'].str.extract("(\d+)-(\d+)").stack().reset_index(1, drop=True)
Out[16]:
Name
Agri    0100
Agri    0199
Agri    0910
Agri    0919
Food    2000
Food    2009
dtype: object
```

Comment: I think the user wanted to expand the ranges as well, e.g. create a 100 rows from `Agri 0100` to `Agri 0199`

Answer (score 0):

This is the top Google search result for "pandas expand ranges to rows", and it doesn't have a very satisfying answer. So here's one that is fast and uses Pandas and NumPy functionality. We start by using `str.extract` as the other solutions do, but then we're going to use `numpy.repeat` and `DataFrame.groupby` to do our expansion.

```py
data = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
('Agric',  '0100-0199'),
('Agric',  '0910-0919'),
('Agric',  '2048-2048'),
('Food',   '2000-2009'),
('Food',   '2010-2019'),
('Soda',   '2097-2097'),
], columns=('Name', 'SICs'))

# Extract the SICs minimum and maximum
data = pd.concat((data, data['SICs'].str.extract("(?P<SICs_min>\d+)-(?P<SICs_max>\d+)")),axis=1)

# Set their types to be integers, as str.extract comes up with objects
data = data.astype({'SICs_min':np.int32, 'SICs_max':np.int32})

# Add a SICs_len column for the size of our range. We're also adding an original_index column we'll need later.
data = data.assign(SICs_len=data.SICs_max-data.SICs_min+1, original_index=data.index)

# Create a new dataframe by repeating the values from the original SICs_len times. So the rows from the
# first range will be repeated 100 times, the second range will be repeated 10 times, etc.
new_data = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(data.values, data.SICs_len, axis=0))
new_data.columns = data.columns
new_data = new_data.astype(data.dtypes)


# At this point, we've expanded our ranges, but we don't have a 
# column that represents the number that the range has been expanded into.

# To get that, we're going to use the SICs_min column, plus a counter that resets
# every time we get to a new SIC range. 

# The counter can be made by grouping by the original SICs range and then doing
# a cumulative sum of a column of just ones.

cumsum = new_data.assign(ones=np.ones_like(new_data.index)).groupby('original_index').ones.cumsum()

# This looks like 1-100, followed by 1-10, etc. We need it to be 0-99, 0-9 etc. so we subtract one
# before we add it to the SICs_min to get the actual SIC number.

final_data = new_data.assign(SIC=new_data.SICs_min + cumsum - 1)
print(final_data)
```

Our final data frame looks like this:

```
      Name       SICs SICs_min SICs_max SICs_len original_index   SIC
0    Agric  0100-0199      100      199      100              0   100
1    Agric  0100-0199      100      199      100              0   101
2    Agric  0100-0199      100      199      100              0   102
3    Agric  0100-0199      100      199      100              0   103
4    Agric  0100-0199      100      199      100              0   104
..     ...        ...      ...      ...      ...            ...   ...
127   Food  2010-2019     2010     2019       10              4  2016
128   Food  2010-2019     2010     2019       10              4  2017
129   Food  2010-2019     2010     2019       10              4  2018
130   Food  2010-2019     2010     2019       10              4  2019
131   Soda  2097-2097     2097     2097        1              5  2097

[132 rows x 7 columns]
```

You might want to tidy it up by removing some columns:

```py
final_data = final_data.drop(columns=['SICs_min', 'SICs_max', 'SICs_len', 'original_index'])
```

You might ask, why bother with the `original_index` column? Well, this allows us to have multiple overlapping ranges, even ranges that start with the same number. Try duplicating the last 'Food' range and give it a different Name - you'll see that both ranges end up in the final table. In fact, even if you give it the same name, you still get both ranges! Without the `original_index` column, there's no other way to do this.